# Migrating server and backup server to bigger RAID 1 (software) arrays

Tags: linux, ubuntu, migration, software-raid

I have 2 boxes.  The server (actually an ownCloud server) and a backup server.  Both are running Ubuntu servers.

The main server has a RAID 1 array of 2x2TB drives.
The backup server has a RAID 1 array of 2x4TB drives (it is running incremental time machine type rsync type backups).

I am getting 2 new 8TB drives so I can double the capacity.

What I want to do is

1. mirror the backup drives (2x4TB) to the two new drives (2x8TB).
2. then want to mirror the server drives (2x2TB) to the original backup drives (2x4TB) so they can be reused as the new server drives.

I think this is right?

The question is exactly how should I do this?  What is the correct way to mirror one RAID 1 array to another bigger RAID 1 array?  I want to maintain the full file system including hard links.

I am actually replacing the backup box, not sure if this is relevant/helps.  There are various partitions on both boxes.

Answer (score 0):

In such scenario I often cold boot inside a cloning tool, especialy if you use the software raid of the hardware.

I clone the drive to a backup destination; ie; an usb drive, test if the backup is ok, re-create the bigger array and re-image back into the new array.

Keep in mind I rarelly do linux gear, I know my plan work on windows os, as they can detect the unused space and re-allocate after, it would be to test on your side to know if it's doable in ubuntu.